# Django Rest Framework - Filter fields of nested relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to return a nested representation of `Customer` with `Image` objects, where a `Customer` can have many `Images`.

Currently, the GET request returns a list of **ALL** images from the `Image` queryset for each `Customer` object as shown below.
How can I show only related `Image`(s) for each `Customer` object in a list instead?

```
# The 'images' field currently returns all images rather than related images to the customer id.
[
   {
       'id': 1,
       'name': 'John Doe',
       'images': [
           {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo.jpg', 'customer': 1},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar.jpg', 'customer': 2},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'foobar.jpg', 'customer': 3},
           ...
       ]
   },
   {
       'id': 2,
       'name': 'Jane Doe',
       'images': [
           {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo.jpg', 'customer': 1},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar.jpg', 'customer': 2},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'foobar.jpg', 'customer': 3},
           ...
       ]
   },
   ...
]
```

This is my current setup

Example Models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Example Serializers

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # My Customer nested relationship is expressed using ImageSerializer as a field
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'images')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Please let me know if my question is unclear and I will update my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the related name as the field for the reverse foreign key.

In your case this would be;

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image_set')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Consider it like a reverse FK query - `Customer.objects.first().image_set.all()`

---

DRF Docs on this are here; [Reverse Relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations)

Django docs on reversing relationships are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

---

Using the `_set` reverse lookup like this is the django default. It's possible that you may add your own [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to a relationship.

An example from the django docs;

```
# Declare the ForeignKey with related_query_name
class Tag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tags",
        related_query_name="tag",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# That's now the name of the reverse filter
Article.objects.filter(tag__name="important")
```

For your example you might add something like;

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="images"
    )
```

The django default of `Customer.image_set` will still work, but you can then do `Customer.images.all()` because you've defined that `related_name` for the relationship.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I didn't know about DRF reverse relations before. Cheers for the help.